# SwiftUI - Present onboarding screen/walkthrough

Tags: swiftui

I wish to add/present an onboarding screen/walkthrough after user's have signed up. However, I'm already using `.environmentObject()` in my `SceneDelegate`. The reason being is I wish to check the Auth state of a user (I'm using FireStore).

So this is my SceneDelegate:

```
if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: InitialView().environmentObject(SessionStore()))
    self.window = window
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

This is my InitialView:

```
struct InitialView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    func listen() {
        session.listenAuthenticationState()
    }
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if session.isLoggedIn {
                MainView()
            } else {
                SignInView()
            }

        }.onAppear(perform: listen)
    }
}
```

My `SignInView()`is pretty self explanatory. And my `MainView()` is essentially my `TabView`

```
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {

        ZStack() {
    
            Color(SYSTEM_BACKGROUND_COLOUR)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            TabView{
                HomeView().tabItem({
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
            })
            DiscoverSearchView().tabItem({
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
            })
                CameraView().tabItem({
                Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
            })

            ActivityView().tabItem({
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            })
            ProfileView().tabItem({
                Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
            })
    

                }.accentColor(Color(SYSTEM_ACCENT_COLOUR))
        
    }
    }
}
```

So right now I have an OnboardingView, but I am not too sure how to present it:

```
struct OnboardingContentView: View {
    @State private var step = 1
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(SYSTEM_BACKGROUND_COLOUR)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                Text("Welcome to").font(.caption).foregroundColor(Color(SYSTEM_FONT_COLOUR))
                    .padding(.top)
                Text("Anexis").bold().font(.largeTitle).foregroundColor(Color(SYSTEM_FONT_COLOUR))
                GeometryReader { gr in
                    HStack {
                        VStack(spacing: 40) {
                            Image("logo")
                            Text("1")
                                .padding()
                                .animation(Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 40, damping: 7).delay(0.1))
                        }.frame(width: gr.frame(in: .global).width)
                        VStack(spacing: 40) {
                            Image("logo")
                            Text("2")
                                .padding().fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                                .animation(Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 40, damping: 7).delay(0.1))
                        }.frame(width: gr.frame(in: .global).width)
                        VStack(spacing: 40) {
                            Image("logo")
                            Text("3")
                                .padding().fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                                .animation(Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 40, damping: 7).delay(0.1))
                        }.frame(width: gr.frame(in: .global).width)
                    }.multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(SYSTEM_FONT_COLOUR)).font(.title).padding(.vertical, 60).frame(width: gr.frame(in: .global).width * 3)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .offset(x: self.step == 1 ? gr.frame(in: .global).width : self.step == 2 ? 0 : -gr.frame(in: .global).width)
                        .animation(Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 40, damping: 8))
                }
                HStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Button(action: {self.step = 1}) {
                        Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                            .padding().scaleEffect(self.step == 1 ? 1 : 0.65)
                            
                        }
                    
                    Button(action: {self.step = 2}) {
                                     Image(systemName: "2.circle")
                                         .padding().scaleEffect(self.step == 2 ? 1 : 0.65)
                                         
                                     }
                    Button(action: {self.step = 3}) {
                                     Image(systemName: "3.circle")
                                         .padding().scaleEffect(self.step == 3 ? 1 : 0.65)
                                         
                        }
                }
                .animation(.spring(response: 0.4, dampingFraction: 0.5)).font(.largeTitle).accentColor(Color(SYSTEM_ACCENT_COLOUR))
                
                Button(action: {
                    NavigationView {
                        HomeView()
                    }
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Continue")
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                    }.padding(.horizontal)
                        .padding().background(Capsule().fill(Color(SYSTEM_ACCENT_COLOUR))).accentColor(Color(SYSTEM_BACKGROUND_COLOUR)).opacity(step == 3 ? 1 : 0)
                        .animation(.none).scaleEffect(step == 3 ? 1 : 0.01).animation(Animation.interpolatingSpring(stiffness: 50, damping: 10, initialVelocity: 10))
                }
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to add another `.environmentObject()` to my SceneDelegate but I get errors. So I thought I can use `UserDefaults` but I get an error

> No ObservableObject of type ViewRouter found

So how could I go about checking if the user has installed the app for the first time, present the onboarding view and also how would I dismiss the onboarding view? Use a `NavigationLink` to my `HomeView` when the `Continue` button is clicked?

Edit :

```
class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var currentPage: String
    init() {
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didLaunchBefore") {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didLaunchBefore" )
            currentPage = "onboardingView"
        } else {
            currentPage = "homeView"
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: *No ObservableObject of type ViewRouter found* - what is `ViewRouter`?

Comment: @pawello2222 Ah my bad, I've added my ViewRouter class. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a top level view used for *routing* - displaying views conditionally:

```
class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentPage = "onboardingView"

    init() {
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didLaunchBefore") {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didLaunchBefore")
            currentPage = "onboardingView"
        } else {
            currentPage = "initialView"
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct RoutingView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewRouter: ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if viewRouter.currentPage == "onboardingView" {
                OnboardingView()
            } else {
                InitialView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct OnboardingView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("OnboardingView")
            Button("Continue") {
                self.viewRouter.currentPage = "initialView"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You also need to replace the root view with:

```
RoutingView()
    .environmentObject(SessionStore())
    .environmentObject(ViewRouter())
```

Note: I assumed you want to present the InitialView and not the HomeView (as the user may not be logged in). If that's not true you can easily replace `InitialView` with `HomeView`.